# Public folder exploration under Struts2 web application

Tags: struts2

I want to publish some resources (folders and files) under a folder inside the WebContent folder of my Struts2 application and allow free directory exploration of that folder contents.

WebContent/public-folder/*.*

Does somebody know how to achieve this?

All my attempts fail with the classical ‘There is no Action mapped for action name public-folder’

I am using Sitemesh decorator, and have defined next exclude pattern:

```
<excludes>            
<pattern>/*public-folder*</pattern>
</excludes>
```

It seems that I’m unable to escape away from Struts2 control.
Thanks…

Answer (score 5):

**Warning**

> There is no Action mapped for action name public-folder

**because of `/*` for filter**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

---

**Solution**

**`struts.xml`** ([Preventing Struts 2 from Handling a Request](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/static-content.html))

```
<!-- value : regular expressions -->
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/public-folder/.*?" />
```

**`[Tomcat] /conf/web.xml`**

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>listings</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value> <!-- default is false -->
</init-param>
```